# Elementary OS Problems: Installation, Resolution and Graphics

Tags: graphics, resolution, amd, radeon, install

I'm relatively new to Linux distros, and my first shot at it was Elementary OS Loki. I installed it to my old PC with no hitches. It was an old i3, and a GTX 1050.

However, now, I installed Elementary OS Juno to my new laptop; an HP 14s that has a Ryzen 3 3200U, a dedicated Radeon 530, an integrated Radeon Vega 3, and 4GB of RAM. I used Rufus to write the ISO into a bootable USB. When I booted it up for installation, **I couldn't get past the splash, so I typed in nomodeset.** I got past the splash, and into a low-res installation desktop. I installed the OS, and everything went swell until it finished and I rebooted only to find that I still couldn't get past the splash screen unless I type in nomodeset. And when I did type it in, **the desktop had no other resolution but 1024x768. My laptop monitor has a resolution of 1366x768.** **xrandr doesn't work** because the monitor shows up as unknown and I just recently discovered that **nomodeset disables Radeon**. How do I fix this?